# How to remove an error phpMyAdmin #1932

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have installed the last version of XAMPP for MAC OS, Apache runs without any problems, MySQL too, but when i attempt to create, edit, or import smth, always appears error with MySQL answer: #1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine.

Notice, that i didn't edit configuration files, this error started appearing after installing program.

Tried to find answer everywhere, but without result. All information i found was devoted to error #1146, but i think that it isn't the same one...

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you use MAMP which supports well with MAC OS

Answer (score 0):

It seems like, the database you have selected is 'phpmyadmin'. Where there is no table with name 'pma__tracking'. Hope you should select another database.

Comment: Every table included in standard archive is unable because of this error) All i have done is installed program... That's all... Can you help me to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Create a new database and add new tables to that. You will get tutorial from google

Comment: And one more note: phpmyadmin.pma__tracking is native phpmyadmin table, i think...

Comment: i can't even create something, despite the fact that i'm root user. It seems to be more global problem